# Select a Value from Database and Return another Value in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my models.py, I have two CharFields set that the Admin can log into and input.  One has a friendly name and the other has a file path directory attached to it:

models.py

```
class IssuingCA (models.Model)
    ICA_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ICA_name
```

In my views.py, I reference these fields so that I can use them in a drop-down `<select>` tag later:

views.py

```
from .models import IssuingCA
--snip--
"""This is the main page"""
def index(request):
    issuers = IssuingCA.objects.order_by('ICA_name')
    issuerOptions = {'issuers': issuers}
    return render(request, 'index.html', issuerOptions)
--snip--
"""This is the results page"""
def results(request):
    issuer = request.POST['selectedIssuer']
    return render(request, 'results.html', {'issuer': issuer}
```

In my html code, I create a for loop for each ICA_name from my model.

index.html

```
--snip--
<select name="selectedIssuers">
    {% for icas in issuers %}
    <option>{{ icas }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

results.html

```
--snip--
This is your result:<br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="200">{{ issuer }}</textarea>
--snip--
```

Right now, when I submit this data and return it via a simple post, it returns the ICA_name field I selected as expected.  How can I get the result to show the matching filepath when the ICA_name is selected? I eventually want to pass this data (the filepath) onwards to more functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select box, pass a value for your options:

```
<option value="{{icas.filepath}}">{{ icas }}</option>
```

Comment: Wow. It was really that simple.  Thank you so much!!